# How to access resource file in C#?

Tags: c#

i have add .zip file to my resource 
how can i access that zip file ?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Add your resource to the project in the project properties...(which you did)

Then it's simple...

```
var zipFile = MyNamespace.Properties.Resources.My_Zip_File;
```

Comment: Sorry, I will bubble wrap it next time.

Comment: @Gabe While I agree that the answer is good and acceptable, I also find that it would have been more insightful by explicit showing the type instead of using *var*.

Comment: When in same namespace it could be left out.

Comment: What is the return type from My_Zip_File? Is it a path string, binary, stream or Path object?

Answer (score 9):

Visual Studio Community 2015 answer:

1. In *Project*->*Properties*->*Resources*->*Files*, add My_Zip_File.zip, accessed by double-clicking *Properties* in *Solution Explorer*.
2. Locate *Solution Explorer*->*Resources*->My_Zip_File.zip, click this item and look at *Properties*. *Build Action*="None" and *Copy to Output Directory*="Copy always".

The file is now accessible programatically. The path and file is part of the assembly when debugging and when the progam is installed as a final publish. It compares favorably against using absolute path. Example C# header:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
```

Example C# code:

```
String strAppPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
String strFilePath = Path.Combine(strAppPath, "Resources");
String strFullFilename = Path.Combine(strFilePath, "My_Zip_File.zip");
```

`
For example, we can read the file as Stream and we can also open the file using strFullFileName.

[Source of reference](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319292)

Comment: It works well for me when I set the 'Build Action' to 'Content' in the mentioned step 2