# Inline method to read a resource file .txt

Tags: c#

Following my code I used when I did not put the file "text.txt" in the resource files:

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("text.txt");
```

Now the file "text.txt" is in the resource files, this code it gives me error. How to solve?

Comment: Please be more specific: which error and what are you trying to accomplish with this file.

Comment: You might want to look at the official documentation: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access resource file in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964942/how-to-access-resource-file-in-c)

Comment: Do you need a StreamReader, a TextReader or just the contents by any means?

Comment: StreamReader, It gives me error as "file not found".

Comment: You'll have to explain, why would you need a Streamreader and not a TextReader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a Textfile to your Resources, than you can get the Content of this Textfile as String via Properties.Resources:

```
string textFileContent = Properties.Resources.NameOfYourResource
```

You could also make a Property to access your the Content of your ResourceFile:

```
public string YourResource
{
    get
    {
        return Properties.Resources.NameOfYourResource
    }
}
```

If you want to read your ResourceFile Line by Line or mabe only the first line:

```
string text = Properties.Resources.text;

        using(TextReader sr = new StringReader(text))
        {
            var firstline = sr.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("FIRSTLINE: " + firstline);

            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It gives me error as "file not found". Where did I put Properties.Resources?

Comment: very strange, how did you add the resource?

Comment: The name of resources is: Resources.

Comment: Under your ProjectDirectory there is a Folder called "Resources" is your text.txt file in there?

Comment: @user2843341 sine's answer is correct, go to project -> properties -> resource and look there how you call the file.

Comment: Ok, but I have not put Properties.Resources, because I do not know where to place it.

Comment: what do you mean by "you have not put Properties.Resources"!?!

Comment: you should place it there where you need the content of the textfile?!? It´s just one line of code you can put it anywhere, as long as it is in a class or method!

Comment: Is correct: string textFileContent = Properties.Resources.("text.txt"); System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(textFileContent);?

Comment: no this is not correct why do you need a StreamReader? And you NEVER can do something like Resources.("text.txt"), this want even compile! If you want the content of this file just put the code from my answer where you need the filecontent or do you need the filecontent in form of a StreamReader?

Comment: In summary, If I have two files: "a.txt" and "b.txt", how do I read ONLY to b.txt?

Comment: if you have added both as resource to your project than via Properties.Resources.b

Comment: Perhaps we have not understood, how do I show the first line of b.txt in console?

Comment: updated the answer, but don´t forget to add the file as a resource!