# how to access a resource created from the properties of a project in c #

Tags: c#, resources

I have created this resource in my project
[image]

And Now I don't know how to access to it in my code

Any idea please?

regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access resource file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964942/how-to-access-resource-file-in-c)

Comment: Resource.ResourceName

Answer (score 0):

Solved

> Properties.Resources.DefaultPath