# How to constantly get same directory path from inner directory

Tags: c#, graphics, io, system

I am using c#.

I have a project running at path:
`D:\USER\Desktop\Prgramming\C++ 2020-2021\project\projectGraphics\projectGraphics\bin\Debug`
The Project directory looks like this:
[image: Project directory]

I want to get constantly (in any computer) from an .exe file in Debug to an image in Resources efficiently. How can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964942/how-to-access-resource-file-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use WinForms or WPF?

Add the image as a "resource" in your project.
[image: Add Image to ResourceFile]
Afterwards you can use

```cs
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.myImageFile);
```

to access the image.

Comment: I want to set the Image I selected as in `Image ButtonBase.Image`. Can I do that?

Comment: You can use it anywhere in the project as background, as an image, as what you want, but the file will be stored in resource file, not like a simple image file. Otherwise you can add file to the project and set "Copy to output directory"  property  to "Copy always" or "Copy as newer" and use path to them.